# Carousel with images for next/previous on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Have you seen the sliding effect on [BBC website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/), where when the next and previous arrows are moused over, it shows an image icon of the coming slide? Is this a jQuery plugin? If so, which plugin is this and can I customize it to my needs?

I am looking to build a carousel, but I am not sure if this type of sliding effect is achievable with minimum effort. Is this possible without a plugin, and how much effort would it take? Should I go with a plugin (link please) or create my own (need ideas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BBC use a custom JavaScript Library -> http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/

An alternative is the Nivo Slider -> http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

IMO there is no need to creating something when its already been written, so a plugin is the best way to go

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is ther a plugin for something this http://cricketnext.in.com/ on the left side(slider)